# How to connect to a remote database in spring boot

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot

I have a back-end project where I have my connection in the application.properties file the problem is that when I put the remote credentials in the application.propeties file my build fails because I cannot connect to the sql. I think that the project is trying to connect to the local server database( because locally my credentials are different that the remote). Can someone please explain how can I do this. This is my application.propeties code.

PS: I am using sql-server and my database in my remote server is also 127.0.0.1.

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/expensedb?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
```

Comment: how can be remote server as `localhost` ?

Comment: Is localhost on the remote side.

Comment: i think you need to provide ip of remote sever instead of `localhost`. try it

Comment: ok I will :) thanks

Comment: should I use jdbc:mysql://51.255.174.85:3306/expensedb?useSSL=false or should I drop something @Ankit

Comment: your application war is deployed on local or on remote machine ? if your application war is on remote machine, then your database is also on same machine or other machine?

Comment: I cant build the project because it says that he cant connect to mysql server

Comment: kindly post stacktrace of your error here on your question